# run command after finishing protobuf_generate

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to patch PROTOBUF_FINAL out of generated protobuf files, in order to do this I've created a simple bash script that will do so for me, but the problem I'm now facing is that I haven't been able to get it to run after protobuf_generate itself, only before it or not at all.

Internally it seems protobuf_generate runs add_custom_command for each file provided to it, and after all of that it sets an output variable containing all the generated files (_generated_srcs_all), so I tried depending on that with a custom command but with that it just never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to depend on the generated files list which is stored in this variable ?
note: supposing you are talking about the function `protobuf_generate`

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/ee35b2da4b6d633eadcc105e5232319b47b494a7/cmake/protobuf-config.cmake.in#L141

Comment: I tried doing this yeah, but didn't have any success (I made it output to a variable and made the command depend on it but nothing happened), also yes I meant protobuf_generate my mistake